# parallel fork pipe

Tags: c++, c, fork, pipe

```
void doWork(){

  int fd[2];
  int pret = pipe(fd);

  close(0);
  close(1);
  int dret = dup2(fd[1], 1);
  close(fd[1]);

  while(1){

    char buf[256];
    system("whoami");
    int rret = read(fd[0], buf, 256);

    if(/* something interesting */){
      return;
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  int children = 2;

  for(unsigned work = 0; work < children; ++work){

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0){
      doWork();
      break;
    }
  }
  int status;
  wait(&status);

  return 0;
}
```

What is wrong with this example?  I'm trying to have each child process to call an external program, then read the output of that program from the pipe.  My code only works when children is set to 1.

EDIT:  I'm trying to achieve task-parallelism with fork/pipes.  There is no communication between the parent and the child processes.  Each child process executes an external program, reads the output, processes the output, and continues till the desired output is found.

Comment: What's the problem you have with several children? Can you explain the behaviour?

Comment: I take back what I said before.  With multiple child process it runs fine.  The problem is that with more than one child process the program take VERY long time to complete even though it should be faster, but with just one child process it takes only seconds.  I'm running it on SunOS 5.10; maybe that has something to do with it?

Answer (score 6):

You need to create the pipe before you `fork()`, not after.  In your code, only the child process will have the pipe.  You need both processes to share it.

Eg.:

```
int fd[2];
pid_t pid;

if (pipe(fd)) { /* TODO: handle error */ }

pid = fork();
if (pid < 0) { /* TODO: handle error */ }

if (pid == 0)
{
   /* We are the child.  Set fd[1] as stdout. */
   if (dup2(fd[1], 1)) { /* TODO: handle error */ }

   /* Close fd[0]; this process doesn't need it. */
   close(fd[0]);

   do_work();
   exit(0);
} 
else
{
   /* We are the parent... */
   /* Close the other guy's write fd. */
   close(fd[1]);

   /* Now read from fd[0] */
   /* Possibly waitpid() on child pid, etc. */
}
```

Also: I like to call `fflush(stdout);` before I `fork()`.  Otherwise you will observe weird behaviors with `printf()`.

Comment: The child process doesn't need `fd[1]` either, after it's been duplicated to stdout, so that should be closed too.

Comment: @caf - Agreed.  But not closing `fd[0]` has worse consequences, so I'm always sure to do that.  Closing `fd[0]` means you'll get `SIGPIPE` writing to `fd[1]` if the parent dies.  But if you get in that situation with `fd[0]` in your process, you could end up with a hang if the pipe's buffer is full.  OTOH `fd[1]` will get closed at process exit so leaving it open isn't as much of a big deal.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't help.  I'm trying to achieve task-parallelism with pipes and fork. Each child process makes a 'system()' call.  The output of that external program is redirected to a pipe so it can be read from and processed.  The child continues this loop until something "interesting" happens.  The problem with my code is that multiple child processes seem to interfere with each other.

Comment: also note that there is no need for the child and parent to communicate with each other.  That's why I created the pipe in the child.

Answer (score 1):

You want to spawn child that will then execute some sub-process, parse it content, interpret it, and then exit ? If so, you need to `fork` twice for each task you want to create. The first time to create the child that will handle the result of the subprocess, the second time to launch the subprocess.

Something like that :

```
void ExecuteCommandAndInterpretResult(const char* command)
{
    int fd[2];
    if (pipe(fd))
        exit(1);

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        exit(1);

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        if (dup2(fd[1], 1))
            exit(1);

        close(fd[0]);
        execl(command, basename(command), NULL);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        int status;

        close(fd[1]);
        // do something with output from command

        wait(&status);
        exit(0);
    }
}

#define CHILDREN 2
int main()
{
    unsigned int i;
    pid_t pids[CHILDREN];

    for (i = 0; i < CHILDREN; i ++)
    {
        pids[i] = fork();
        if (pids[i] < 0)
        {
            // TODO: handle error
        }
        else if (pids[i] == 0)
        {
            ExecuteCommandAndInterpretResult("/usr/bin/ls");
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < CHILDREN; i ++)
    {
        if (pids[i] > 0)
        {
            int status;
            waitpid(pids[0], &status, 0);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `popen()` in the child to execute `whoami`?